# TYPO3 PHP not working on website

Tags: php, ajax, iis, typo3

On my Website with TYPO3 I want some PHP scripts to show some data on my Homepage. Without TYPO3 it works well, however using TYPO3 it does not show results.

I have some JS files included via TypoScript, which runs PHP files with the use of ajax.

I use the following AJAX call to my PHP scripts:

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'fileadmin/php/loadprices.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',

        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loadingSpin').show();
        },
....
```

The JS is executed properly, so it isn't the issue for that. 
Without TYPO3, the PHP script is running properly too.
On a local server (apache), the PHP script is executed.

On the IIS 6 Server the PHP script does not work.

Does anybody know some tips? 
greets

Comment: can you add some version infos of your programms? in regard of TYPO3 I could imagine some .htaccess configuration which restricts execution of php in subfolders of /fileadmin as this is a possible security breach. all php should be stored in extensions (typo3conf/ext/*/) and in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably run your website with `realurl`? In that case if you are not working with baseUrl your link will be altered if it is opened from a "subdirectory" like `yourdomain/link1/link2.html`. The relative path `fileadmin/php/loadprices.php` becomes `yourdomain/link1/fileadmin/php/loadprices.php` that way.

A simple solution is to change it to an absolute url:

```
url : '/fileadmin/php/loadprices.php',
```

Comment: Hey, thank you a lot for your tip, I found out that the relative path was incorrect. "../php/..." solved it for me!